# Importing GnuCash data into Quicken

Tags: import, cross-platform, quicken, gnucash

I've been looking and it seems like no one has ever moved from GnuCash to Quicken!

I know that GnuCash can import .qif's but Quicken cannot import GnuCash's XML files and I can't see any way to convert it.

I've asked Quicken for help and they told me that I had to input all data by hand.  I have way too much data to input by hand; I track multiple people's finances.

c'mon guys and gals, someone has to have succeeded in doing this somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GnuCash FAQ](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Importing.2FExporting_Data) has something on that topic.

Comment: http://gnucashtoqif.sourceforge.net/
This kind of worked, I got all the names of the accounts in but all of the transactions are missing.  I can deal with this for now, but something tells me that the program that's backed by the multi-million dollar company should have more options right?

Comment: blsub6: They don't give a damn. And why should they? An ad probably gives them more new customers than GnuCash has total, while still being cheaper than writing an importer. Plus, import capability is acknowledging a competitor. This is easy to do as the underdog, but if you do that as the big player, that means you're in trouble (see Microsoft's "I'm a PC"). Enough ranting for today, so to sum up: I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a converter/importer by the Quicken folks.